# What's better in that context - `for` or `while`

Tags: c++, c

I've read somewhere that one should use a `for` loop when you are iterating over some sort of array/sequence/list/whatever you call it and a while loop when your loop needs to stop at a certain condition.

So, what if I have something like this

```
int len = 0;

for(; s[len] != '\n'; ++len) {
    // some processing

    if (someCondition) {
        return len;
    }
} 

// if done iterating, return len
return len;
```

Is this okay to use the `for` loop in this context or would a `while` loop be preferable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd probably write it this way:

```
int len;
for (len = 0; s[len] != '\n'; ++len) {
    ...
}
return len;
```

Just because then I say in the `for` statement what the range is I'm interested in (index 0 up to the first newline character).

I generally choose between `for` and `while` on the basis of what the code looks like, rather than on where I stand in the hairsplitting semantics argument what the difference is between "some kind of range" vs "the period from now until some condition is false". I don't think it's a problem to play around a bit with `for`. The third part of the statement is "specially visible" in the way that an increment at the end of a `while` loop isn't, and I think that's enough to justify using it with a minor contortion like your empty first part.

Comment: +1 Putting the initializer inside the for statement seems like a pretty good idea.

Answer (score 2):

The `for` loop is OK. You have the increment `++len` at the place of loop control, which I find preferable. You don't forget it somewhere at the end of the loop body. And it even works well when you use `continue`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, a for loop is the only one that's going to accept that kind of syntax so that's what I'd say you should use.  Besides that...it actually doesn't really matter in the slightest.  Do what is easy to read.

Answer (score 2):

Given your quoted code, I'd use a `for` loop, but I would put the initializer *inside* the `for` statement as an assignment:

```
int len; // <== Not here

for (len = 0; s[len] != '\n'; ++len) {  // <== Here
    // some processing

    if (someCondition) {
        return len;
    }
}
```

This is *exactly* what the `for` structure is for: An initialization, test, and increment.

Answer (score 1):

It really doesn't matter. They are equivalent in terms of efficiency. You could do either of the following:

```
for(; s[len] != '\n'; len++) { ... }

while(s[len] != '\n') { ... len++; }
```

The `for` loop is perhaps more easily readable in this case, and the `while` is perhaps a bit more clever, but they're really functionally equivalent.

EDIT: True, the `for` doesn't increment the counter until after the first loop. Fixed it.

Comment: Not true. The for loop will not run the increment instruction in it's first pass, but the while loop will.

Comment: The `while` would not work as expected, because the `len` variable is incremented before it is used in the `return` statement in the loop body.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a While and put the `len` incrementation inside the condition verification `s[++len] != '\n'` :D
But I guess it's what flavour you prefer really :)

Comment: That results in different behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd go with this:

```
int len = 0;
for (; s[len] != '\n'; ++len) {
    // some processing

    if (someCondition) {
        break;
    }
} 

// if done iterating, return len
return len;
```

But really, it's all down to readability, as there's no real semantic difference between `for` and `while` loops. Use whatever format you feel conveys the meaning of your code the best. In the above case I chose `for` because of the `len` loop variable, if that wasn't there I would have went with `while`.

Comment: That's wrong. `len` has the scope of the for loop itself, and is not accessible anywhere outside of the for loop.

Comment: You'd still need to declare `len` outside the `for` declaration.

Comment: Ah yes, serves me right for browsing SO past 10PM. Corrected, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating, and a `for` loop is more compact. You can achieve the same thing in either case anyway, but for this I prefer to use `for` because you have all the loop drivers (condition, counter increase) in the beginning.

```
int len = 0;
while (s[len] != '\n')
{
    // do stuff
    if (something) return len;

    ++len;
}
return len;
```

vs.

```
int len;
for (len = 0; s[len] != '\n'; ++len)
{
    // do stuff
    if (something) return len;
}
return len;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter of taste. Both are equivalent.

But with years I have happend to really prefer the while loop over for loop. I prefer when lines are short, and the for has a tendency to put 3 different steps in the same line.

```
int i=0;
while(s[i] != '\n')   
{
    // some processing

    if (someCondition) 
    {
        return i;
    }
    ++i;
}
```

but as i said, it's a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1):

What about foreach!

```
int len = 0;
for each (char& c : s) {
    // some processing
    if (someCondition || c=='\n') break;
    len++;
} 

// if done iterating, return len
return len;
```

Comment: i think in c++0x the grammar is for(char &c : s)

Answer (score 1):

I see majority of the post are using `for`.

This post here will give you idea in case you want to pursue with `while`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main ()
{
    int counter=0;
    while(somecondition) {
        if (s[counter]!='\n')
        {
        //some processing       
        }
    ++counter;
    }
}
return len;
```